# Concatenate two 2 dimensional lists into a new list

Tags: python, list

DISLCAIMER:  I am new to Python

I would like to create a concatenated 2-D list in Python by combining 2 existing 2-D lists.  I start with 2 lists:

```
listA = [[a, b, c], [1, 2, 3]]
listB = [[d, e, f], [4, 5, 6]]
```

and i want to make a new list (while preserving listA and listB):

```
listC = [[a, b, c, d, e, f], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]
```

If I try to add them as with 1-dimensional lists, I get:

```
listA + listB
result = [[a, b, c], [1, 2, 3], [d, e, f], [4, 5, 6]]
```

I have also tried:

```
listC = listA
listC[0] += listB[0]
listC[1] += listB[1]

# This may be giving me the result I want, but it corrupts listA:

Before: listA = [[a, b, c], [1, 2, 3]
After:  listA = [[a, b, c, d, e, f], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]
```

What is the right way to make a new list of the data I want?

I could also work with a tuple:

```
listC = [(a, 1), (b, 2), (c, 3), (d, 4), (e, 5), (f, 6)]
```

But don't know the method for that either.

I am currently using Python 2.7 (raspberry pi running raspbian Jessie), but Python 3.4 is available if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways:

```
listC = [listA[0] + listB[0], listA[1] + listB[1]]

listC = [x + y for x, y in zip(listA, listB)]
```

Are probably the two simplest

Comment: Thank you! I actually just found this on my own list(listA) + list(listB) does exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new list, e.g with list-comprehension

```
listC = [a+b for a,b in zip(listA, listB)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a functional approach if you want learn more:

```
In [13]: from operator import add
In [14]: from itertools import starmap

In [15]: list(starmap(add, zip(listA, listB)))
Out[15]: [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]
```

Note that since `starmap` returns an iterator if you don't want the result in a list (maybe if you just want to iterate over the result) you shouldn't use `list()` here.

Comment: @downvoter If there is anything wrong with my answer I'd be happy to hear about that.